# bash: nodemon : command not found while running nodemon app.js

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs, nodemon

when i m running this code: nodemon app.js it is giving the command not found error.Below is package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "whisperauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

when i m running npx nodemon app.js the mongo db is giving insertOne(),  timeout errors and when i m running node app.js the code is working perfectly fine. I just want be able to run nodemon app.js. when i run npx nodemon app.js or anyother method it gives error like:
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
Below is the connection code for mongodb:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended:true
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB");

const userSchema = ({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

//Routes
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  return res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
  return res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  return res.render("register");
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
  const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  newUser.save(function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.render("secrets");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: try `npm run nodemon app.js`, would need more info about the timeout errors. If you want to just run `nodemon app.js` you need to [install nodemon globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)

Comment: it is returning err:  Missing script: "nodemon"

Comment: what to add in the scipt

Comment: seems to be script already in your package.json, so you can try `npm start` but i assumed you had tried that already

Comment: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 why other method except node app.js prevent mongodb from doing its work

Comment: delete node_modules folder then Run the command "npm i"

Comment: I would need to see the connection code for mongo db. Nodemon is doing more than just running the app, you might not be properly awaitng the connection event

Comment: ok ill post the connection error

Comment: ok now can you help

Comment: `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017` means there is no process listening on your machine on port 27017. Are you sure your mongo database server is running?

Comment: `npm run foobar` is used to run a script named `foobar` that is defined within the `scripts` section in your `package.json` file. There is no `nodemon` script in your `package.json`, but only a `start` script (which calls `nodemon`). So either use `npm run start` instead of `npm run nodemon`, or define a `nodemon` script in your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Run Command
"npm install"

if not working run

"npm i nodemon"

Comment: i had done all things like uninstalled, installed , globally installed everything but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Got it I just uninstalled node.js and reinstalled it and then installed nodemon globally. Now its working fine.